# Storing AppSettings Key Value in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, key-value

I am looking for some best practices/ gotchas for storing an appsetting (key, value) in mongodb.

1) Is it better to store it as a Key-Value type where each entry is a new document on mongo or
2) Have a single document with property: value (Obviously I will hit the 16MB limit if the app settings are huge).

My aim is to call the service to load the settings in a singleton and use the settings.

Comment: 16MB is a whole lot of settings!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev true . I am thinking of a worst case scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try and decide if it is feasible that the app settings document will grow to more than 16MB.
If this might happen you have no choice but to store a collection of `{key:value}` and possibly also some identifier in case you support multiple applications (e.g. `{key:value, appId:value}`). Otherwise, I would just store a JSON of the settings for each app, this is a classical use of the JSON structure. 
In general, when your requirements change with your application needs, a JSON is a more flexible solution. One example is supporting nested settings which is trivial with JSON, but less so with collection.